# Get data from a web socket in a Spring Boot web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I am new to both Spring Boot and Websockets.
I am comfortable with Java and have read a few things on Websockets and Spring Boot framework.
I need to communicate with a Web socket and get the data in an existing Spring Boot web app.
Can anyone let me know where I can start and any good online resources ? I did Google, but most of the examples are difficult for me to grasp in a short time. If possible, also explain it to me conceptually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To create a basic websockeet applicaiton in spring boot
You will need to:

**- First, Enable Websocket support, For example by using:**

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {


    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

}
```

**- Second, Create a message-handling controller:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

**- Create a browser client**

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}
```

I think you can start with this example, https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: How to send data to client anonymously. I mean even if the client does not send any data through WebSocket, how to send data to the client from server-side through WebSocket?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to a similar question:
[SockJS Java Client Implementation for non-web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870207/sockjs-java-client-implementation-for-non-web-application/41870714#41870714)

Within, you can find an example of a client able to send/receive websocket data.